# (Select Procedure) SUM of two different SMALLINT fields from different tables. I am using SQL Manager for Interbase and Firebird

Tags: select, sum, firebird, firebird2.5, interbase

I want to get the SUM of two different SMALLINT fields from different tables in select procedure. I am using SQL Manager for Interbase and Firebird

The values of field TRAINING_SRCVDAYS in Table E are 1 and 2 while the value of field LEAVE_WITHPAY_NUMDAY in Table A is 2.

```
                       Table E        Table A
                           1             2
                           2
```

Expected output(Sum)           3             2

real output to my procedure    3             4

here is my code. please help

```
CREATE PROCEDURE AAAASAMPLE(
  UPDATEHANDLER VARCHAR(50) CHARACTER SET ISO8859_1 COLLATE ISO8859_1,
  WHAT_YEAR VARCHAR(50) CHARACTER SET ISO8859_1 COLLATE ISO8859_1)
RETURNS(
  FULLNAME VARCHAR(100) CHARACTER SET ISO8859_1 COLLATE ISO8859_1,
  TRAINING_SRCVDAYS SMALLINT,
  LEAVE_WITHPAY_NUMDAY SMALLINT,
  SICKLEAVE SMALLINT)
AS
BEGIN
  FOR
    SELECT
      C.EMP_SURNAME || ', ' || C.EMP_FIRSTNAME || ' ' || C.EMP_MIDDLENAME || ' '||C.EMP_SUFFIXNAME,
      SUM(E.TRAINING_SRCVDAYS),
      SUM(A.LEAVE_WITHPAY_NUMDAY),
      SUM(E.TRAINING_SRCVDAYS) - SUM(A.LEAVE_WITHPAY_NUMDAY)

    FROM LEAVE_TABLE A, POSITION_TABLE B, EMP_TABLE C, TRAINTRN_TABLE D, TRAINTYP_TABLE E
    WHERE    

    (A.EMP_PK =: UPDATEHANDLER AND A.LEAVE_FROM_YEAR =: WHAT_YEAR AND A.EMP_PK = C.EMP_PK
    AND A.POSITION_PK = B.POSITION_PK AND B.POSITION_CLASS_REF = 0 ) 

    AND 

    (D.EMP_PK = C.EMP_PK AND D.TRAINING_PK = E.TRAINING_PK AND D.EMP_PK =: UPDATEHANDLER 
    AND E.TRAINING_SRVCCRDT = 'Yes' AND E.TRAINING_FROMYEAR =: WHAT_YEAR)

     GROUP BY 
     C.EMP_SURNAME || ', ' || C.EMP_FIRSTNAME || ' ' || C.EMP_MIDDLENAME || ' '|| C.EMP_SUFFIXNAME

    INTO
      :FULLNAME,
      :TRAINING_SRCVDAYS,
      :LEAVE_WITHPAY_NUMDAY,
      :SICKLEAVE
  DO
    BEGIN
      SUSPEND;
    END
END;
```

Comment: The problem is that if you join a table with 2 rows to a table with 1 row, then that 1 row is repeated once for each row in the first table. You need to `sum` per table and then join (I don't have time to work this into an answer right now, hence the comment). PS You should really switch to explicit joins, it makes it easier to read the query.

Comment: `C.EMP_SURNAME || ', ' || C.EMP_FIRSTNAME ` - not the best code, actually. As long as one column gets NULL - then the all expression would be NULL

Comment: If you want your values *grouped by* value in Table_A - then you have to ask for it - `SELECT  SUM(E.TRAINING_SRCVDAYS),
      A.LEAVE_WITHPAY_NUMDAY,
      SUM(E.TRAINING_SRCVDAYS) - A.LEAVE_WITHPAY_NUMDAY GROUP BY A.LEAVE_WITHPAY_NUMDAY` /////
Additionally, as a side note:  - there is no point in turning a single `SELECT` into a stored procedure - you just force SQL engine to cache the value instead of building an optimizing data-fetching-path. Turn this `SELECT` into a `VIEW` not a procedure

Comment: and if you want to group by BOTH tables C and A - then ask for it too, ask for grouping by both TWO columns

Comment: Sir @Arioch'The , what is the ideal code alternative for this (C.EMP_SURNAME || ', ' || C.EMP_FIRSTNAME)  one sir. Tnx for your comments sir I am very new to sql and programming.

Comment: if you use it rarely, then you can wrap each field into COALESCE function: `COALESCE(C.EMP_SURNAME, '') || ', ' || COALESCE(C.EMP_FIRSTNAME, '')...`  - this would have another problem, empty components would lead to double commas "xxx, , yyy". Maybe you can use LIST function. And perhaps i would consider adding the specific C.FULL_NAME field, that you never would change directly, but instead you would make "BEFORE UPDATE OR INSERT" trigger, that would calculate the field as you please and make and save its value